# Does a partial k-tree graph must be planar?

Tags: graph-theory

Does a partial k-tree[1] graph must be planar?

What about small values of k ? (like 2 or 3).

Thanks.

[1]-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_k-tree

Answer (score 1):

Each (finite simple) $2$-tree is planar. We can inductively construct its straight-line plane drawing, placing new vertex sufficiently close to the midpoint of the edge to which endpoints it is adjacent. On the other hand, a non-planar graph $K_{3,3}$ is a partial $3$-tree.